# Android ObjectAnimator background Colour and text

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I currently have a list view and I want to have the animation change colour depending on a status from the network. Sio far this is working, but it doesn't look too fluid, would there be a way to have so it would go from transparent, to the colour normal but without a long fade in between.

Here is my code so far.

```
List<ObjectAnimator> arrayListObjectAnimators = new List<ObjectAnimator>();

ObjectAnimator bgColor = ObjectAnimator.OfInt(
    DoorItemLayoutView,
    "backgroundColor",
    Color.Transparent, 
    color,
    color,
    Color.Transparent);
bgColor.SetEvaluator(new ArgbEvaluator());

ObjectAnimator doorTxtColor = ObjectAnimator.OfInt(
    doorName,
    "textColor", 
    Color.White, 
    textChangeColour, 
    textChangeColour, 
    Color.White);
doorTxtColor.SetEvaluator(new ArgbEvaluator());

ObjectAnimator siteTxtColor = ObjectAnimator.OfInt(
    doorSiteName, 
    "textColor",
    Color.White, 
    textChangeColour, 
    textChangeColour, 
    Color.White);
siteTxtColor.SetEvaluator(new ArgbEvaluator());

ObjectAnimator doorIconBackground = ObjectAnimator.OfInt(
    doorImage.Background,
    "background", 
    Color.Transparent, 
    Resource.Drawable.door_active_background,
    Resource.Drawable.door_active_background,
    Color.Transparent);
doorIconBackground.SetEvaluator(new ArgbEvaluator());

arrayListObjectAnimators.Add(bgColor);
arrayListObjectAnimators.Add(doorTxtColor);
arrayListObjectAnimators.Add(siteTxtColor);
arrayListObjectAnimators.Add(doorIconBackground);

var objectAnimators = arrayListObjectAnimators.ToArray();
AnimatorSet animSetXY = new AnimatorSet();
animSetXY.PlayTogether(objectAnimators);
animSetXY.SetDuration(2000);
animSetXY.Start();
```

Comment: Could you explain what do you mean by "a long fade in between"? Could you share the animation you have now?

Comment: I cant share the screen due to non disclosures, but the fade ie the transition between the transparent and the colour, then from the colour to the transition. it goes to black them to transparent, instead of going from the colour to transparent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason you are seeing this effect:

> it goes to black them to transparent, instead of going from the colour to transparent.

is because Color.Transparent is actually black with alpha 0.
If you want to get rid of the black you need to copy the target color and set its alpha to 0 and use that color instead of Color.Transparent